# Code won't create an XML node and skips over it

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using XML to save a basic file for a text based adventure game. The XML string does save except for the Inventory nodes aren't being created. I'm using the same process to save the quests; the quests and completion of the quest saves.

```
//Create the "InventoryItems" child node to hold each InventoryItem node
XmlNode inventoryItems = playerData.CreateElement("InventoryItems");
player.AppendChild(inventoryItems);

//Create and "inventoryItem" node for each item in player's inventory
foreach (InventoryItem item in this.Inventory)
{
    XmlNode inventoryItem = playerData.CreateElement("InventoryItem");

    XmlAttribute idAttribute = playerData.CreateAttribute("ID");
    idAttribute.Value = item.Details.ID.ToString();
    inventoryItem.Attributes.Append(idAttribute);

    XmlAttribute quantityAttribute = playerData.CreateAttribute("Quantity");
    quantityAttribute.Value = item.Quantity.ToString();
    inventoryItem.Attributes.Append(quantityAttribute);

    inventoryItem.AppendChild(inventoryItems);
}
```

This is the code to create and save to the inventory nodes and quest nodes. I set breakpoints in the foreach statement. The code gets into the statement but no further than the first line in that block; `XmlNode inventoryItem = playerData.CreateElement("InventoryItem");` I have been stuck on this problem any help would be appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't you reverse the calls on `AppendChild` - `inventoryItems.AppendChild`?

Comment: That call is making inventoryItems a child node of the player node.

Comment: And than you make `inventoryItems` child of `inventoryItem` ...

Comment: That call is making inventoryItems a child node of the player node previously created in the function.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand what point in the code you were talking about, yes that's a mistake. Still the app never gets to that line of code.

Comment: That seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks, I always miss my stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inventoryItem` should become a child of `inventoryItems` at the end of the `foreach` statement.

```
inventoryItem.AppendChild(inventoryItems);
```

Should be:

```
inventoryItems.AppendChild(inventoryItem);
```